# Mute notifications while using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Every time when my program using ProcessPoolExecutor it prints that loading some packages. How to mute this? And what is the name of that notification so that I know what to ask?

```
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link had the answer for this question. It's in Chinese, hence pasting the English translation of it below.
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41295952/article/details/105214322

This error message shows that when you install new software, update numpy or do something, the old numpy is not uninstalled, and the two versions of numpy cause conflicts.

Solution:

1. Enter cmd to uninstall numpy: pip uninstall numpy
2. Reinstall numpy: pip install numpy
3. If numpy is not available at this time, check the .libs folder and delete another dll file in it, it should be available

For me numpy got uninstalled on uninstalling. When I tried to install numpy again, strangely it said numpy is already installed. But numpy is still working for me and the warning is gone.